# How to get the mm-dd-yyyy format

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
select *, 
       datediff(Y,employee.joiningdate,getdate()) "retirementdate" 
from employee
```

How to get the mm-dd-yyyy format ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datediff function doesn't return a date, so you can't format it as a date. If it's date formatting you want then you should take a look at this msdn article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

If you just want to know how to format a date in sql :

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 110)
```

But you should not convert dates in sql. Keep dates as dates and do the formatting in your application.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 110)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 110)
```

get look in this http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx